Python - Having troubles using open()
I have a small tool I made for work, basically opens some websites and copies stuff to my clipboard so I can quickly answer questions that get asked a lot. I wanted to add a new feature to the bottom of my tool that can lookup the vendor of a MAC using the OUI. I have a file called oui.txt and 2 python files all in the same directory. I started by first building my mac lookup script in its own file. It looks like this....

mac = input("Enter MAC: ").upper().replace(':', '')[:6]
ouiList = []
filehandle = open("oui.txt", 'r')
dataList = filehandle.read()

for vendor in dataList.split('\n'):
    ouiList.append(vendor.strip())
for i in ouiList:
    if mac in i:
        print(i)




Pretty straight forward, it works no problem. However, when I move it over to my work tool, I consistently get an error saying it cannot find oui.txt even though both my python files and oui.txt are in the same folder. I cannot understand why one file can find it and the other cannot. I've tried a few different methods that I have seen suggest on here, including using the Path module to set the path, and using the OS module to set the directory, which is the current iteration of my code. I thought maybe it had to do with my code being inside an while True statement with If blocks inside of it, so I moved it outside of everything as a function, then had my if statement call the function, but the same thing happens.
Here is the current code with all the extra work stuff cut out and here is a random MAC I've been using to test with 90:DE:80:21:36:7E
import os

import PySimpleGUI as sg
import webbrowser as wb
from tkinter import Tk
from AppOpener import open

def get_vendor():
    mac = values["-MACINPUT-"].upper().replace(':', '')[:6]
    ouiList = []
    here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    filename = os.path.join(here, 'oui.txt')
    filehandle = open(filename, 'r')
    dataList = filehandle.read()

    for vendor in dataList.split('\n'):
        ouiList.append(vendor.strip())
    for i in ouiList:
        if mac in i:
            window["-MACINPUT-"].update(i)


default_column = [


    [sg.Input(default_text='', key="-MACINPUT-")],
    [sg.OK("LOOKUP MAC", key="-LOOKUPMAC-")],
]

template_list_column = [
    [sg.Column(default_column)]
]


layout = [
    [sg.Column(template_list_column)]
]

window = sg.Window("Quick Links", layout, no_titlebar=True, grab_anywhere=True, resizable=True, size=(200, 500), right_click_menu=sg.MENU_RIGHT_CLICK_EDITME_VER_EXIT)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == "-LOOKUPMAC-":
        get_vendor()

window.close()


I've tried finding the file with Path and Os modules. I've tried moving the code out of the while loop into its own function. I also slowly removed code bit by bit, but it never finds the file until the only thing left is function.

It may be how you launch the file and the current directory isn't what you think it is.
import os then print(os.getcwd()) to find out.

is your work tool in a separate dir?

The directory containing the Python files and the current working directory are not necessarily the same. Consider python somedir/script.py. The current working directory is not somedir.

Work tool is in the same directory. For simplicity, my directory looks like this:
oui.txt
main.py (My work tool)
test.py (Where i originally wrote the mac lookup script while testing it)
test.py has no problem running and finding oui.txt. No needs to set a path or use os to change directories.
main.py has the same exact code in it, just copy and pasted over. It fails to find the oui.txt
Why would one Python script have no trouble finding the file, but the other one does.? I did it get working by just turning test.py into a function, then importing the function and calling it.

Should change current working directory to your directoy before you use the filename which is without the filepath, or you should specify what the filepath for your files.
import os

current_path = os.getcwd()
print(f"Current working path: {current_path}")

my_path = "D:/"     # Path to file
os.chdir("D:/")

current_path = os.getcwd()
print(f"Working path now: {current_path}")

with open("mac.txt", "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip())

Current working path: D:\
Working path now: D:\
00-B0-D0-63-C2-26
00-1B-63-84-45-E6
01-80-C2-00-00-00


No need to call readlines; you can iterate over f directly.

This particular way is not recommended. Why read the entire file into memory when you don't need to?

Updted as above.

I decided that if it works in the separate file, I will just turn that file into a function and import it. Works fine that way.
I would still love to know why it wasn't working.
